# Как подключить базу управления пользователями для Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net

Здравствуйте, есть локальная база данных на **MS SQL Server 2014**, использую среду разработки **MS VS Express для Web 2015**. Требуется подключиться к базе данных созданной в **MS SQL Server 2014** используя класс **Membership**. Я, при помощи утилиты **aspnet_regsql.exe** настроил свою локальную базу. Создал "*Веб-сайт веб-форм ASP.NET*". Застрял на Web.config, изменил в нём:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnection"
  connectionString="Data Source=ANDREW;Initial Catalog=Test3;AttachDbFilename=F:\моя папка\Data\Test3.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

А какие параметры менять дальше не пойму. Перелопатил кучу сайтов, но всё, что нарыл не работает. Плюс не могу запустить **Web Site Administration Tool - инструмент администрирования веб-сайтов**. На официальном сайте написано *"выберите в меню Веб-узел пункт Конфигурация ASP.NET"*, но данный пункт в моей версии IDE отсутствует, а другие способы запуска **WAT** не срабатывают. В общем хочу узнать как до конца донастроить подключение к БД и как можно запустить **WAT**.

Answer (score 1):

Может кому поможет вот ссылка: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOWvO_Vb3oM&list=PL60U9axemuzSmYuVNKrob5DgenpDOgHw5&index=75. Бывает возникает ошибка c jquery, решение - добавить в web.config код:

```
 <appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
 </appSettings>
```